# CREDENTIAL_ERROR Starting GLASSFISH Internal Server

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, credentials

#### SOLVED - See bottom of post

Firstly, I will state that I have read all the existing posts regarding this problem and none of the suggested solutions have worked.

After upgrading eclipse to Indigo SR2 and to java 7, I was not able to start Glassfish, either embedded or separate installation.

After a week of this and because my PC was getting sluggish, I decided a full rebuild of my PC was required, so I reset the PC back to factory settings and started again. 
My spec now looks like this...

Windows XP SP3 - Firewall Disabled as 3rd Party solution installed
Java 7 - jdk1.7.0_03 + jre
Eclipse Indigo SR2

hosts file...
127.0.0.1     localhost

I installed the latest Glassfish Plugin from: http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/indigo
However, just as before the rebuild, when I try and start the server, I get the CREDENTIAL_ERROR.
I'm now super frustrated as I would have expected this completely clean install to just work.

I disabled the firewall, but that made no difference.

I then tried to start the embedded server manually. e.g. asadmin start-domain, and it started fine. I can stop it from Eclipse, but as soon as I try and start it again I get the CREDENTIAL_ERROR. Grrrrhhh!!!

I also spotted this entry in the eclipse .log file...

!MESSAGE GlassFish: error reading one jmx portjava.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${JMX_SYSTEM_CONNECTOR_PORT}"

...which may be relevant as the final line of a verbose manual startup of the server looks like this...
[#|2012-04-09T15:33:16.625+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.jmx.org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver|_ThreadID=41;_Thre
adName=Thread-23;|JMX005: JMXStartupService had Started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://HOME:8686/jndi/rmi://HOME
:8686/jmxrmi|#]

Many thanks
Chris

#### SOLVED

Darn it. Just after posting this, I stumbled upon this link...
http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISHPLUGINS-72
...which suggested that the Anti-Virus (not the firewall) being the culprit and lo and behold, it was. I removed port 8080 from scanning and the server fired up without a problem.
Now I need to work out if I've opened up a security hole.

#### UPDATE

I decided to install a separate Glassfish instance and the problem started over again. In then end I discovered that I had to disable the NOD32 HTTP Scanner entirely to allow the server to start. Re-enabling it got the CREDENTIAL_ERROR again. There didn't seem to be any configuration setting that would get around this. I'll have to fire an email off to ESET to see what they suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with about the same configuration. Only my eclipse is Version: Indigo Service Release 1, and I work in an environment where it isn't allowed to disable a firewall.

In my case it helped to switch to a previous version of Java (jdk6-u30), which wasn't what I intended. So I installed the newest version of the JDK at this moment: jdk1.7.0_04, and used this as the -vm value in de eclipse.ini.

This still left some complains about a Currentversion of 1.7 when 1.6 was expected by our version of Glassfish's asadmin. Which were worked around by changing the registry back to 1.6, instead of the 1.7 version added by the installation of the jdk1.7.0_04.

After these changes I could start and stop Glassfish from within eclipse without the CREDENTIAL_ERROR.